# How to build a universal binary for tiff library on MAC

Tags: xcode, macos, tiff

I want to build a universal binary tiff library on my mac, and the tiff library was downloaded from http://www.libtiff.org/. The way how I compile and install the library is very straightforward:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

However, the library is built for x86_64 as the target machine is 64 bits, and I expect to have a library that is universal (can run on 32 and 64 machines). I check the help information form ./configure, but little information is available on universal binary. Any ideas? Thanks.